# VBA SOLIDWORKS Pack and Go rename doesn't work if there's a design table linked to the part file (Controlling from Excel)

Tags: vba, rename, solidworks

I have a code that takes a specific part and is supposed to "Pack and Go" to another specific location while renaming these new created files, however if I have a design table linked to the part I am trying to "Pack and Go" the renaming of files doesn't happen. What could be the cause of this problem?

The code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks
Dim swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
Dim swModelDocExt As SldWorks.ModelDocExtension
Dim swPackAndGo As SldWorks.PackAndGo
Dim OpenFilePath As String
Dim OpenFileName As String
Dim SavePath As String
Dim SaveName As String
Dim myFileName As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim pgFileNames As Variant
Dim pgFileStatus As Variant
Dim status As Boolean
Dim statuses As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim partDocExt As SldWorks.ModelDocExtension

Sub PackAndGo()

Call Calculate_TFVPM_FormatSketchFileName

OpenFilePath = "G:\Format Sketch\FormatSketch.SLDPRT"
SavePath = "G:\Format Sketch\Temp\"
SaveName = NewSaveName

On Error Resume Next
Set swApp = GetObject(, "SldWorks.Application")
Set swModel = swApp.OpenDoc(OpenFilePath, swDocPART)

'Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
OpenFilePath = swModel.GetPathName
OpenFileName = Mid(OpenFilePath, InStrRev(OpenFilePath, "\") + 1, InStrRev(OpenFilePath, ".") - InStrRev(OpenFilePath, "\") - 1)

Set swModelDocExt = swModel.Extension

'Get Pack and Go object
Set swPackAndGo = swModelDocExt.GetPackAndGo

'Include any drawings
swPackAndGo.IncludeDrawings = True

'Set folder where to save the files
status = swPackAndGo.SetSaveToName(True, SavePath)

'Get files path
status = swPackAndGo.GetDocumentSaveToNames(pgFileNames, pgFileStatus)
For i = 0 To UBound(pgFileNames)
    myFileName = Mid(pgFileNames(i), InStrRev(pgFileNames(i), "\") + 1, InStrRev(pgFileNames(i), ".") - InStrRev(pgFileNames(i), "\") - 1)
    myExtension = Right(pgFileNames(i), Len(pgFileNames(i)) - InStrRev(pgFileNames(i), ".") + 1)

    'Replace name
    If LCase(myFileName) = LCase(OpenFileName) Then
        pgFileNames(i) = SavePath & SaveName & myExtension
    End If
Next

'Set files path
status = swPackAndGo.SetDocumentSaveToNames(pgFileNames)

'Flatten the Pack and Go folder structure; save all files to the root directory
swPackAndGo.FlattenToSingleFolder = True

'Pack and Go
statuses = swModelDocExt.SavePackAndGo(swPackAndGo)
        
'Close initial template
swApp.CloseDoc (swModel.GetPathName)
        
End Sub
```

Comment: the code will rename the current part file to the name "NewSaveName". If the Excel file name needs to be changed you have to specify what is the old name to look for and its new name.

Comment: How do I do that? The old filename is constant "FormatSketch"

Comment: I made some tests, even if the name of the Excel file is correctly changed, pack n Go through an error when attempting to set the name with SetDocumentSaveToNames. An other method would be to copy the files with a standart method, then update the references with http://help.solidworks.com/2012/english/api/sldworksapi/solidworks.interop.sldworks~solidworks.interop.sldworks.isldworks~replacereferenceddocument.html

Comment: Name changes correctly UNLESS there's a linked design table to the part you're trying to pack and go

Comment: Yes. That's what I meant. Although Pack n go seems to work with a linked Table if the names are not changed. (Only using SetSaveToName to set the path)

Comment: So setting the names afterward (except the name of the design table file) with ReplaceReferenceDocument will work.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for a given part with a design table

```
Option Explicit
Sub PackAndGo()
Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks
Dim swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
Dim swModelDocExt As SldWorks.ModelDocExtension
Dim swPackAndGo As SldWorks.PackAndGo
Dim OpenFilePath As String
Dim OpenFileName As String
Dim SavePath As String
Dim SaveName As String
Dim myFileName As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim pgFileNames As Variant
Dim pgFileStatus As Variant
Dim status As Boolean
Dim statuses As Variant
Dim i As Long

Call Calculate_TFVPM_FormatSketchFileName

OpenFilePath = "G:\Format Sketch\FormatSketch.SLDPRT"
SavePath = "G:\Format Sketch\Temp\"
SaveName = NewSaveName

Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
Set swModel = swApp.OpenDoc(openFile, swDocPART)
'Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
OpenFilePath = swModel.GetPathName
OpenFileName = Mid(OpenFilePath, InStrRev(OpenFilePath, "\") + 1, InStrRev(OpenFilePath, ".") - InStrRev(OpenFilePath, "\") - 1)

Set swModelDocExt = swModel.Extension

'Get Pack and Go object
Set swPackAndGo = swModelDocExt.GetPackAndGo

'Include any drawings
swPackAndGo.IncludeDrawings = True

'Set folder where to save the files
status = swPackAndGo.SetSaveToName(True, SavePath)

'get Paths
status = swPackAndGo.GetDocumentSaveToNames(pgFileNames, pgFileStatus)

'Flatten the Pack and Go folder structure; save all files to the root directory
swPackAndGo.FlattenToSingleFolder = True

'Pack and Go
statuses = swModelDocExt.SavePackAndGo(swPackAndGo)

'Rename file
For i = 0 To UBound(pgFileNames)
    myFileName = Mid(pgFileNames(i), InStrRev(pgFileNames(i), "\") + 1, InStrRev(pgFileNames(i), ".") - InStrRev(pgFileNames(i), "\") - 1)
    myExtension = Right(pgFileNames(i), Len(pgFileNames(i)) - InStrRev(pgFileNames(i), ".") + 1)

    If LCase(myFileName) = LCase(OpenFileName) Then
        Name pgFileNames(i) As SavePath & SaveName & myExtension
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but that code isway too complex beyond necessity and doesn't really update the part and drawing properly, I mean in fact it does but the thumbnails don't update meaning that part is not getting rebuilt properly. By too complex I mean there's only one part and one drawing for this pack and go function and they are always called the same. The design table doesn't relinks to the new one neither (it's not necessary however, I am deleting the design table after rebuilding anyways). There are no assumptions to be made with this one